# Creating gstreamer uridecodebin element inside loop with videomixer

Tags: python, gstreamer

So the problem I'm trying to solve is to take an unknown of incoming URI streams and mix them into one outgoing stream. What I am essentially doing right now is using a for each loop where each iteration I create a source, add in elements like videoscale and the capsfilter, and then link it to the videomixer. Currently I have it working if I just pass in a usb webcam feed with autovideosrc. However, it completely falls apart when I try to use a uridecodebin, due to linking errors.

I know that normally when creating a uridecodebin you have to use the pad-added signal with something like this example.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pygst
pygst.require('0.10')
import gst

import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk

# this is very important, without this, callbacks from gstreamer thread
# will messed our program up
gtk.gdk.threads_init()

def on_new_decoded_pad(dbin, pad, islast):
    decode = pad.get_parent()
    pipeline = decode.get_parent()
    convert = pipeline.get_by_name('convert')
    decode.link(convert)
    pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
    print "linked!"

def main():
    pipeline = gst.Pipeline('pipleline')

    filesrc = gst.element_factory_make("filesrc", "filesrc")
    filesrc.set_property('location', 'C:/a.mp3')

    decode = gst.element_factory_make("decodebin", "decode")

    convert = gst.element_factory_make('audioconvert', 'convert')

    sink = gst.element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "sink")

    pipeline.add(filesrc, decode, convert, sink)
    gst.element_link_many(filesrc, decode)
    gst.element_link_many(convert, sink)

    decode.connect("new-decoded-pad", on_new_decoded_pad)

    pipeline.set_state(gst.STATE_PAUSED)

    gtk.main()

main()
```

However, every example of this that I have found has been assuming that I would always be connecting one uridecodebin to one other element. How would I go about implementing something where the element represented by 'convert' in this example would be different each time I call the function?